# what is wrong in this User search list

Tags: php

How to implement a user list search, where the user will not be listed if the battles value of 0? Listed on user must be a link.

```
// If more than one player to show names List
if (count($data) > 1 && !isset($_GET['linkki'])) {
    foreach($data as $pelaaja) {
        print("<a href=\"".$nykynen_osote_tahan_filuun."?haku=PE&nimi=".$pelaaja->nickname."\">".$pelaaja->nickname."</a>"); // Linkki hakuun print
    }
} else {
    // Print all the information the player if the value is not 0
    $pelaaja_info = $api->get('wot/account/info', array('account_id'=>$data[0]->{'account_id'}));

    foreach($pelaaja_info as $pelaaja_i) {
        // Does not print anything if the player is just a game 0
        if ($pelaaja_i->statistics->all->battles == 0) {
            print ($data[0]->nickname);
        } else {
            print("<span class=\"nick ");
            print("\">");
            print($data[0]->nickname);
            print(" [");
            // THIS NAME OF THE CLAN
            print("] ");
            print("</span>");
            print("<br/>");
```

Comment: can you be more specific in your cases and what you need as the final requirement

Comment: Yes I can, but what would you like to know more?